# Is a program with errors still compiled?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-construction, error-handling

I have a question regarding how programs are compiled. If I am writing a program in c++ and I make a mistake, per say, by typing:

`int x = 4;
cout << x % 10 = 0;
// assignment error`

Will the program still COMPILE this and have errors, or is the program not compiled at all until errors are fixed?

Phrased differently, can compiled code have errors?

Comment: Run it through your compiler and find out? Or rephrase the question, because I'm not alone in thinking .. "huh?"

Comment: @OMerObaid I think this could be difficult to figure it out with an online compiler. He should rather try this on his machine and check the ouptut, while with an online compiler, if it doesn't compile, he can't really check anything excepted the fact it's not ran :)

Comment: Will not compile successfully until there are compiler errors

Answer (score 1):

It's really up to the compiler.  The standard distinguishes
between diagnosable errors and undefined behavior.  In the case
of undefined behavior, anything can happen; in many cases, the
standard has chosen this category because it isn't reasonable to
expect the compiler to even be able to detect such an error.  In
the case of diagnosable errors, the compiler is required to
output a message; beyond that, it may more or less do what it
wants.

In practice, when a compiler detects an error (including, in
some compilers, certain types of undefined behavior), it will
not only output an error message, it will set an internal flag
to prevent code generation, and to cause it to return an error
status to the system (so that the build system will not continue
and try to link), and it will try to resynchronize the input, in
order to find more errors.  (The last isn't always doable
correctly, and it's not rare for a single error to cause
numerous knock-on errors, which don't mean anything.)  None of
this is required, however, and how it happens may vary between
compilers, or even depend on compiler options.  Other compiler
options, like treat warnings as errors, may make the compiler
non-compliant, in that it will fail to compile technically legal
programs.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

All compilers I used do not compile code untill all errors are fixed (unless there are some hidden compiler flags I have never heard about). Compiler, as name suggests wants to compile code. If it has an error it means it cannot understand what was written in the code. If it cannot understand it, it cannot translate it (compile) to another language (either another programming language, or binary).

Also, read wikipedia page on compilers:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler , it should help you understand how compiler works.

Comment: Be careful. C++ is a complex language and is not that simple. There are situations related to the template system where an program with an error can be compiled successfully. For example, a function SFINAEd away which body contains a lot of errors. The body of the function is not parsed until the second phase (the instantation phase), so because the template is not instanced, the code is not checked.

Comment: Technically the program itself is compiled successfully because the program does not contain errors (the program generated). But the template system is just a code generator (i.e. a metaprogramming system), and there are cases (like the example above) where your sourcecode contains errors, but the metaprogram does not use the buggy code, so the generated program has not errors and could be compiled successfully. So a better answer could be **In C++ your sourcecode can contain errors, but only if the final program doesn't use that code.**

Comment: Alas even this is an over-simplification. Consider `if (false) { rarrrrrrrrrrrrrr }`

Comment: @Manu343726 that's not correct. Everything is parsed in the first phase. Some name lookup is also done on that first phase. The only thing not done in the first phase is dependent name lookup. Based on that, I'd argue there are no errors in such a program (the only errors that could show up would require particular template arguments, which are not passed in in the program, QED).